# How to page sql-requests from client to database

Tags: sql, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I am using the Primefaces Datatable component, and the system backend is running Glassfish and Oracle database.

When doing large search-operations, the load on the AppServer becomes too much.
The Appserver always loads  the full resultset, which is too much load.
**I am looking for ways to optimize the load on the Appserver by just selecting a ”page” at the time from the database?**

Using pagination in the Primefaces Datatable results in only a page being transferred to the client. This is fine, but the Appserver still loads the full resultset.

I was thinking that I could perhaps:

1. First do a count(*) towards the db, to see the size of the total
   resultset.
2. Then do a select on only a list of unique identifiers (representing the full select)  into my Appserver SessionBean
3. Then select a page of ”full resultset-data” and return it to the client.

The client could then press a ”Next page” button to have the AppServer fetch a second page from the database.
This fetch would have to use the ’unique identifier”-list (or i could use the ’rownum’-variable to specify the subset of the full select).
 Ie. In practice here I end up doing the pagination ”manually”

**How could I use the Primefaces Datatable component and get control in my Appserver code when the user presses the paginator-buttons?**

Any alternative way of handling this is of course welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrimeFaces datatable supports this out the box. Just wrap your model in PrimeFaces-provided `LazyDataModel` class and implement the desired subselect job in its `load()` method.

Kickoff example (see [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) for complete example):

```
<p:dataTable lazy="true" value="#{bean.model}" ...>
```

with

```
private DataModel<Item> model; // +getter

@EJB
private ItemService service;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    model = new LazyDataModel<Item>() {
        @Override
        public List<Item> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) {
            // We ignore sortfield/sortorder/filters in this simple example. This job is up to you.
            this.setRowCount(service.count());
            return service.list(first, pageSize); 
        }
    };
}

// ...
```

Wherein the `service.list()` returns **exactly** the desired items starting at given index, having the given size and if necessary already sorted/filtered on given parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I understand the Lazyload-mechanism in PF, The full datasource is loaded into the datamodel (ie. into memory). It then does filtering, sorting and paging on that set. This would not perform well when the datasource consists of millions of objects (truly HUGE), and there are, say 100+ simultaneous users. I found out that at least Oracle have smth. called analytical functions (other vendors have similar mechanisms) where the paging is done within the database with no performance-penalty. To use this I would need 'hooks' for the buttons in the Datatable-control.

Comment: @Erik: Huh? What part of `first` and `pageSize` didn't you understand? This isn't supposed to return a whole copy of the DB at all. This would completely defeat the meaning of "lazy loading" and make whole mechanism useless. If you've enabled sorting/filtering then just pass that information to the service so that it can return exactly the desired data.

Comment: I looked into the example at the PF Showcase-page. It seems to me that the full datamodel is cached within the datamodel.<

Comment: It's just a hardcoded example. You need to look at `load` method implementation, not at underlying datasource. This part isn't relevant.

Comment: The code behind `service.list()` is just all up to you. Are you using JPA? Use `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` for pagination and if applicable use `Order` and `Predicate` for sorting/filtering. They ultimately translate to `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` and `ORDER BY`/`WHERE` in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance this far BalusC. I believe I understand the basics now. I have almost gotten the stuff to work, but one final problem.
In my Datatable properties I set the value="#{tableBean.lazyModel}". Then I get a call to the load()-routine, which is fine.
But I get no data in the table in the Gui.
If I then change in the xhtml-file to value="#{tableBean.lazyModel.wrappedData}" (and saves the file (running in Netbeans)), I get data shown in the table.
But if I do a new search, I get no call to the load()-routine, unless I take away the '.wrappedData'.
Any comments on this?

Comment: Have you set `<p:dataTable lazy="true">` as per answer and showcase example?

Comment: Curious, which PF version are you using and which scope is bean put in?

Comment: @SessionScoped 
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId> <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId> <version>3.5</version>

Comment: Looks okay. Did you implement the code as per my answer? I.e. you aren't manually fiddling with `setWrappedData()` or so? Are you sure that `setRowCount()` is also set right? (this should basically set the result of a `COUNT(*)` query).

Comment: I found and removed 2 errors. Thanks for the tip on setRowCount() which I had not put in. It seems to be working ok now. Thanks for the assistance. -Erik